# validating the length of phone field

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have several phone fields on my web page like this:

```js
$("#HomePhoneInput").inputmask({
  "mask": "(999) 999-9999"
});
$("#WorkPhoneInput").inputmask({
  "mask": "(999) 999-9999"
});
$("#CellPhoneInput").inputmask({
  "mask": "(999) 999-9999"
});
```

```html
<input type="text" asp-for="HomePhone" id="HomePhoneInput" placeholder="(___) ___-____" />
<input type="text" asp-for="CellPhone" id="CellPhoneInput" placeholder="(___) ___-____" />
<input type="text" asp-for="WorkPhone" id="WorkPhoneInput" placeholder="(___) ___-____" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.4/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

I'm using [this library](https://plugins.jquery.com/jquery.inputmask/) to mask the fields.

I want to put the restriction on the length of the phone fields. If the user keys in less than 10 characters then as soon as the user tabs out of the phone field, an error message is displayed underneath the field saying "Phone field needs to be 10 character long." This is what I tried:

```
<input type="text" asp-for="HomePhone" id="HomePhoneInput" placeholder="(___) ___-____" minlength="10" maxlength="10" data-msg="Phone field needs to be 10 character long."  />
```

Above does not work on chrome browser.

This is something, I want when the user tabs out of the phone field:

[image]

Comment: Built-in validation doesn't know that the masking characters shouldn't be counted. Check if there's validation in the masking library you're using.

Comment: Also, the browser's validation only runs by default when you submit the form, not when you leave the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe something like this as a hint:

```js
function validate_phone(input) {

  input_value = document.getElementById(input).value;
  input_msg_error = document.getElementById(input + 'Error');
  
  //your logic or validations
  if (input_value.length <= 3) {
    input_msg_error.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    input_msg_error.style.display = "none";
  }
  
}
```

```html
<input type="text" asp-for="HomePhone" id="HomePhoneInput" placeholder="(___) ___-____" onfocusout="validate_phone('HomePhoneInput')" />

<div id="HomePhoneInputError" style="display: none" >
  Your msg
</div>
```

Comment: It works when I didnt put the masking. As soon as I put the masking the validation stopped working. With the masking, input_value.length is always 14. Is thier any work around for that?